# loop googlesearch thru a list of Company Names and return 1 url for each company

Tags: python, for-loop

I am figuring out how to loop googlesearch thru a list of Company Names and return 1 url for each company and export the results (list of urls) to csv. Below is the code for looking at 1 url. The stop is also the tricky part. Should I be doing a nested loop? Could anyone advice on how to modify the code?

```
from googlesearch import search
for url in search("GWI Consulting", stop=1):
    print(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following to see if it helps:

```
import csv
from googlesearch import search

j = 1
with open('result.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
    fileWriter = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for url in search("GWI Consulting", stop=20):
        print(url)
        fileWriter.writerow([j, url])
        j+=1
```

Comment: hi, is there a way to call the search function to iterate row by row in the list such as search()?